# Grouped linear regression prediction on different grouped by group in R

Tags: r, group-by, regression

I'm trying to build models based on specific groups in a dataset and use the models generated to predict fit on a different dataset by following the group restrictions. In other words, using the example below, models built using subset: cyl==4 of original data should be used only to predict subset: cyl==4 of new dataset (data1). Anyone can help with this interesting problem?

I tried to used `data1%>% group_by(cyl)` to specify the new data but that didn't help

Thank you

````
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


data1 <- head(mtcars,20)

x<-mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(fit = list(lm(wt ~ mpg)), 
            data = list(cur_data())) %>%
  mutate(col   = map(fit, augment, newdata = data1%>% group_by(cyl)))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to do this

```
library(dplyr)
models = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(model = lm(wt ~ mpg, data = .))
```

Then access the individual models with

```
library(broom)
tidy(models$model[[1]])
```

Another way to do the same -

```
models <- mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ disp, data = data)))
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer and upvoting if my solution really helped you. Thanks.

Comment: that doesn't work because there are 2 different datasets (mtcars and data1)